# Are there guidelines on systematic reviews of meta-analyses?

Tags: meta-analysis, systematic-review

Systematic reviews are typically performed on single papers. Nevertheless, the concept of "systematic review of meta-analyses" is not new (see, for example, here:[pdf](https://jech.bmj.com/content/jech/60/2/90.full.pdf)). Are there guidelines on how to perform them?

Comment: At a quick glance there does not seem to be anything on the EQUATOR Network site so the answer is probably "No"

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend you several useful sources of guidance on **umbrella reviews** (this is the term commonly used for systematic reviews of reviews, and thus also encompassing systematic reviews of meta-analyses), including those from *The Cochrane Collaboration* on overviews of reviews: https://methods.cochrane.org/cmi/overviews-reviews

Another useful tool guidance is available at *BMJ Medicine*: https://bmjmedicine.bmj.com/content/1/1/e000071

Finally, consider perusing our book on this topic entitled indeed '*Umbrella Reviews: Evidence Synthesis with Overviews of Reviews and Meta-Epidemiologic Studies*' published by Springer: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-25655-9